# Android Studio Git move commited changes to another branch

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

Is there any way from inside Android Studio to copy recently committed changes from a local branch to another local branch?

**UPDATE**

i want this :

```
    d--h
   / 
a--b--c
   \
    f--g
```

to get like this :

```
    d--h
   / 
a--b--c
   \
    f--g--d--h
```

and if it could be done through options in VCS menu, it would be much more easier and quicker than to use console command line.

Comment: You could cherry-pick that commit to another branch.

Comment: there is an update to the question, actually i wanted to copy my work to another companion branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the branch name is branch1, branch2 and branch3 as below:

```
    d--h   branch1
   / 
a--b--c    branch2
   \
    f--g   branch3
```

First, please **checkout branch11 from branch1**, in the bottom-right of android studio, select current branch as branch1, then right click the branch -> select new branch -> branch11.

Second **rebase branch1 to branch3**, VCS -> Git -> rebase -> select branch3 for onto -> select branch1 for from.

Then the structure will as,

```
    d--h   branch11
   / 
a--b--c    branch2
   \
    f--g(branch3)--d’--h’   branch1
```

Comment: I thought rebase was about moving the branch! thanks.

Comment: Yes, It is. So we can create the branch branch11 to "mark" the place.